# Can the GC collect my variable here, even if I use it in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, nested-class

Suppose I create an instance of this `Test` class, which starts a new Thread using a nested class :

```
public class Test
{
    private String _str;

    public Test()
    {
        _str = "Hello world !";
        new TestThread().start(); // Start a background thread
    }


    private class TestThread extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println(_str);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens now if I remove any strong references to my `Test` instance ? The background thread will still be alive and will continue to print the `_str` variable, but I'm afraid that the GC can collect it anytime.

Of course I can create a local copy of the reference (with a constructor : `public TestThread(String str)` and store it in a local variable) but I wonder if this is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TestThread` itself **has** a strong reference to `Test`, so as long as it is not collectable, the instance of `Test` won't be collectable.  Since it's a running thread, the instance of `TestThread` obviously isn't available for collection.

When you create a non-static inner class (TestThread), every instance of that class has an *implicit reference* to an instance of its enclosing class (Test).

See the Inner Classes section of the [Nested Classes Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

You don't have to be "afraid" of what the GC might do.  It won't collect an object that you could possibly reference, unless you're going out of your way to work with weak references.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about gc, but memory visibility of _str is not guaranteed.

You need _str to be final or volatile, to ensure that TestThread sees the correct value.  Also you need to start the thread after the constructor.  The current code lets the this pointer be accessed from another thread before the constructor completes, which invalidates the guarantees for final.

Storing a copy of _str in TestThread (as you mentioned) as a final variable, and then making TestThread a static class would resolve all of this.